# Display two decimal places in java using printf?

Tags: java, printf, double

A sample of the code below

```
double maxHeight;
maxHeight = (Math.pow(speed * Math.sin(angle), 2) / 2 * gravity);
System.out.printf("Maximum height: %.2f", (maxHeight));
```

The error i receive:

> "The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, double)"

What is the simplest solution to printing only two decimal places using printf method or are there any other solutions without creating a decimalFormat?

Comment: I don't get any errors.  Are you using an older version of Java?

Comment: Are you compiling for an older version, say `javac -target 1.4`? Using a JDK that already has a printf, but the target not having varargs. Check the source version too.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that varargs is looking for one or more `Object`s, and you provided a primitive variable. The simplest method is probably just to wrap it:

```
System.out.printf("Maximum height: %.2f", Double.valueOf(maxHeight));
```

Comment: When I try it, it autoboxes the `double` just fine (using 1.8).  Is your workaround necessary only for 1.4 and earlier?  Or are there any later versions that need it?

Comment: @ajb Not sure. `printf` wasn't added until 1.5, so if it's an autoboxing issue, it's a difference after that point.